# Select max date in one column based on unique dates in another

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a data set that is loaded into the database every time the forecast for that particular date is changed.  I need to be able to select the last load_dt for each fore_dt.  An example data set is below:

```
load_dt, fore_dt, data,
1/1/2017, 1/14/2017, 5,
1/5/2017, 1/14/2017, 8,
1/5/2017, 1/15/2017, 9,
1/15/2017, 1/15/2017, 10,
1/17/2017, 1/16/2017, 5
```

Results should look like:

```
load_dt, fore_dt, data,
1/5/2017, 1/14/2017, 8,
1/15/2017, 1/15/2017, 10,
1/17/2017, 1/16/2017, 5
```

The actual data set is much more complex and has a lot of rows.  In the query, I need to be able to select where fore_dt between date and date.

Comment: Shouldn't the second row be `1/15/2017, 1/15/2017, 10,` in your expected result?

Comment: @GurV Yes you are correct.  Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Do you need just three columns in the output, or are there more columns? (It doesn't matter if there are more columns in the input, what matters is the output.) If there are just these three columns, and if performance is critical, you can save some time with the FIRST/LAST function; otherwise what GurV posted is probably the best way.

Comment: There are more than these three fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window function `row_number` to assign sequence number to row within each fore_dt in the order of decreasing load_dt and then select the first row using a simple where clause:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over (
            partition by fore_dt order by load_dt desc nulls last
            ) as seqnum
    from your_table t
    ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: The worked very well!  I was able to adapt the code to use a query result as a table and partition by 2 fields.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking at max()

```
select max(load_dt) as load_dt, fore_dt, max(data) 
    from yourtable
   group by fore_dt
```